# Suppose $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a sequence in $C[a,b]$ such that for every $x \in [a,b]$ there exists a $M_x$ such that $|f_n(x)|<M_x, n\in \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a sequence in $C[a,b]$ such that for every $x \in [a,b]$ there exists a $M_x$ such that $|f_n(x)|<M_x, n\in \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$

Prove that there exist a $c,d \in [a,b]$ with $c<d$ and $M \geq 0$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [c,d]$.

I think i need to use Baire's category theorem but i don't seem to see how to use it...

Any hints?

Kees

Comment: You have the right idea. One way to implement it is to consider, for each $m\in \Bbb N$, the set $F_m=\{x\in [a,b]:\forall n, \vert f_n(x)\vert \leq m \}$. I should also mention this argument is used to prove an important theorem in analysis, the [Banach-Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle)

Comment: how is the union of $F_m$ equal to $X = C[a,b]$?

Comment: Of course, it doesn't equal $X$. But it is equal to $[a,b]$. Then you can use Baire theorem to prove one such $F_m$ has nonempty interior, from which you can conclude the result.